# How can I generate JSON schema from java classes during gradle build?

Tags: java, json, gradle, jsonschema

I have java classes which have fields annotated with `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`. I would like to generate JSON schemas from them during gradle build. I know I can use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema in code which seems to be working but I would like to generate JSON schema during gradle build.

Is there any way how can I do that ?

Thank you for any help. I am new to gradle so sorry if this is dumb question.

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema only generates json-schema draft3 schemas. Anything before draft4 is obsolete, and draft7 is the latest version.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Bolwidt How can I intergrate it into gradle build ? I want to build my module and then after jar is created I want to generate json schema from some classes which it contains. And I want to do all that in one gradle build script.